# Cordova email plugin. Is there a way to set a default sender?

Tags: cordova, email, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins

So I am trying to use the cordova email plugin to email a pdf to an email address that the user specifies. Is there a way that I can also set the sender's email address?

I know I read from the plugin that the email has to be configured on the phone (as in a personal email address through the email app on iphone)

Is there a way I could just specify which email address it is coming from and not have to use the email that is in the email application on the phone to send the pdf?

Comment: no, you can't, the senders email address is the address of the user that sends the mail. You might consider submitting the information and pdf file to a server that sends the email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find an alternative that lets me use an email without configuring it on the mobile device. It works well as long as you have an email configured.